# How to split a string correctly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have this string

```
"C:\Users\testinguser\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\Hello\Jobs\Testing-Online\_vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global PKI\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx"
```

I'm just wondering how can I split from \_ and get the result only like this

```
vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global JLN\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx
```

I've try using -split("\_") but it didn’t work.

```
$Path = "C:\Users\testinguser\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\Hello\Jobs\Testing-Online\_vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global JLN\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx"

$Result = $Path -split('\_')[2]
```

any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: What's the criteria you want to split on? Why not using  `($Path -split 'Testing-Online\\_')[1]`?  ;-)  ... and BTW: "*it's not working*" is not helpful at all. ;-)

Comment: You have to escape special characters like "\" with a "\".  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
$myString = "C:\Users\testinguser\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\Hello\Jobs\Testing-Online\_vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global PKI\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx" -split "(\\_)"
Write-Output $myString[2]
```

Output : `vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global PKI\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx`

Comment: That could be $mystring[1] without the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong. Because of high operator precedence with [2], you're splitting on $null, since ('\_') only has 2 characters.  The parentheses are unnecessary but harmless, since -split is not a function.  Splitting on `'\_'` would give a regex parsing error, so the backslash has to be escaped.  Splitting on `'(\\_)'`, with the parens inside the quotes, would include the divider in the result.

```
$Path = 'C:\Users\testinguser\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\Hello\Jobs\Testing-Online\_vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global JLN\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx'


($Path -split '\\_')[1]

vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global JLN\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx


$Path -split '\_'

parsing "\_" - Unrecognized escape sequence \_.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Path -split '\_'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException


$Path -split '(\\_)'

C:\Users\testinguser\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\Hello\Jobs\Testing-Online
\_
vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global JLN\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx


'\_'[2] -eq $null

True
```

You can use one of the [string.split .net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-string()-system-stringsplitoptions)) function overloads where a string array is the first argument (not character array), but it requires a second argument.  Then you don't have to worry about escaping regex characters.  It's easier with a single character seperator.

```
# string[] Split(string[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)

$path.split([string[]]'\_','None')
# $path.split((,'\_'),0)

C:\Users\testinguser\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\Hello\Jobs\Testing-Online
vti_history\101376\Shared Documents\Global JLN\Legacy Stuff\Vehicle Credential Trackers\Tracker_JLN_records_USE.xlsx
```

See all the overloads:

```
$path.split

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string[] Split(Params char[] separator)
string[] Split(char[] separator, int count)
string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)
string[] Split(char[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)
string[] Split(string[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)
string[] Split(string[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)
```